# Two asymmetric matrices - multiplying

Tags: matrices

I don't understand why the Wolfram's result of multiplication of matrices

Wolfram said:

$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975\\
\ 0.395413 & 0.4946 & 0.109988\\
\ 0.386671 & 0.492879 & 0.12045\
\end{vmatrix}
*
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 1 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 0.405875 & 0.395413 & 0.386671
\end{vmatrix}
$

But some friends said:

$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975\\
\ 0.395413 & 0.4946 & 0.109988\\
\ 0.386671 & 0.492879 & 0.12045\
\end{vmatrix}
*
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 1 & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\ 0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975
\end{vmatrix}
$

What is right and why?

Comment: Wolfram is right, but only if you interpret $|1\ 0\ 0|$ and the vector on the right-hand side of the first equation as column vectors.  Your friends are wrong.  If you interpret $|1\ 0\ 0|$ as a row vector the product is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the difference between right multiplication and left multiplication of vector.
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975 \\
0.395413 & 0.4946 & 0.109988 \\
0.386671 & 0.492879 & 0.12045
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 0.405875 \\ 0.395413 \\ 0.386671
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975 \\
0.395413 & 0.4946 & 0.109988 \\
0.386671 & 0.492879 & 0.12045
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.405875 & 0.496625 & 0.0975
\end{pmatrix}
$$